# Executing User Defined Function via Classic ASP Function

Tags: encryption, asp-classic, adodb, parameterized-query

OK, I am trying to write a Classic ASP function that will call a SQL function and return the output.
I am trying to use a paramaterized ADODB connection but I don't quite know how these work. Trying to learn the correct way.

The SQL function just takes two string input where one is a "salt" and the other the actual text and turnes it into a hex.
Works fine in SQL but I just can not get it to work through classic ASP.

I keep getting, 
ADODB.Command error '800a0cc1'

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

```
Sub Encrypt(plainString)
    strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT dbo.Encrypt('xx', '?') as keycode"
    Set cnnEncrypt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnnEncrypt.open CONNSTRING

    Dim cmd1
    Set cmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd1.ActiveConnection = cnnEncrypt
    cmd1.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd1.Parameters(0) = plainString      (**Original Error Occured Here!!!!**)
    Set rsEncrypt = cmd1.Execute()

    If not rsEncrypt.EOF Then
        Encrypt = rsEncrypt.Fields("keycode").Value
    Else
        Encrypt = "blank"
    End If

    ' Clean Up    
    rsEncrypt.Close    
    Set rsEncrypt = Nothing    
    cnnEncrypt.Close    
    Set cnnEncrypt = Nothing    

End Sub
```

New Working Version after reviewing "Cheran Shunmugavel" answer.
Calling on site like this

< % Response.Write Decrypt(Encrypt("test")) % >

You can't print the Encrypted code to the page because it is Binary.  You would need a Binary to String function.
I converted from Sub to Function because I wanted the function to return a value.

```
Function Encrypt(byVal plainString)
    strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT dbo.Encrypt('xx', ?) as keycode"
    Set cnnEncrypt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnnEncrypt.open CONNSTRING

    Dim cmd1
    Set cmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd1.ActiveConnection = cnnEncrypt
    cmd1.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd1.Parameters.Append cmd1.CreateParameter("", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(plainString)+1, plainString)  
    Set rsEncrypt = cmd1.Execute()

    If not rsEncrypt.EOF Then
        Encrypt = rsEncrypt.Fields("keycode").Value
    Else
        Encrypt = "blank"
    End If

    ' Clean Up    
    rsEncrypt.Close    
    Set rsEncrypt = Nothing    
    cnnEncrypt.Close    
    Set cnnEncrypt = Nothing    
End Function
```

And here is the decrypt function.

```
Function Decrypt(byVal plainString)
    strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT dbo.Decrypt('xx', ?) as keycode"
    Set cnnDecrypt = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnnDecrypt.open CONNSTRING

    Dim cmd1
    Set cmd1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd1.ActiveConnection = cnnDecrypt
    cmd1.CommandText = strSQL
    cmd1.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd1.Parameters.Append cmd1.CreateParameter("", adVarBinary, adParamInput, LenB(plainString)+1, plainString)  
    Set rsDecrypt = cmd1.Execute()

    If not rsDecrypt.EOF Then
        Decrypt = rsDecrypt.Fields("keycode").Value
    Else
        Decrypt = "blank"
    End If

    ' Clean Up    
    rsDecrypt.Close    
    Set rsDecrypt = Nothing    
    cnnDecrypt.Close    
    Set cnnDecrypt = Nothing    
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't need delimiters around the parameter placeholder. SQL Server will handle it appropriately.

```
strSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT dbo.Encrypt('xx', ?) as keycode"
```

---

Secondly, the `Parameters` collection is initially empty and must be populated before you try to access it (i.e., the line `cmd1.Parameters(0) = plainString`). There are several ways of doing this, but I prefer creating the parameters manually using the [`CreateParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Append cmd1.CreateParameter("", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(plainString), plainString)
```

---

Also, it's not apparent from your code, but make sure you've got the ADO constants defined, either by [referencing the type library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525307%28VS.90%29.aspx), or by [including adovbs.inc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Getting closer, updated question with new version of code and marked the previous with where the error occured.  Thank you for explaining the parameter error that kind of makes since.  The page has adovbs.inc included.  After making changes I am still not geting the desired results, not printing the encrypted code on page or storing in variable.  Am I just reading or calling it wrong, it's late about 3am Sunday and maybe I am just totally missing it.  Will take a better look on Monday :).

Comment: OK, not a problem with anything above, I believe the issue is that the data returned from the function is a binary field and I can not simply write that to the screen.  So I guess I need some kind of Binary to String Conversion.

Comment: Solved all my issues, related to this part at least :).  Thank you Cheran for the help.